# create a col with diff between this and last val in R

Tags: r

This is just as example on how we can create a new col in data which is just calculated from another col.

`data$percentage <- with(data, (p*100))`

I want to create a col which is a difference in value between this and the last row.

Something like this:
`data$diff_p <- with(data, (p[this_row] - p[this_row - 1]))`

I know I can iterate the whole data in a for loop and get it done in some lines.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `c(NA, diff(data$p))` ?

Comment: See also the `data.table::shift` function or the `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::lead` functions.